# Scraping a list of prices using Python

Tags: python, html, database, web-scraping

I am trying to analyze the data on this website: [Electricity prices](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/dayAheadPrices/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=01.10.2018%2000:00%7CCET%7CDAY&biddingZone.values=CTY%7C10YAT-APG------L!BZN%7C10YAT-APG------L&dateTime.timezone=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET%20(UTC%201)%20/%20CEST%20(UTC%202))

I tried to do it using Beautiful Soup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get('https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/dayAheadPrices/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=01.10.2018+00:00%7CCET%7CDAY&biddingZone.values=CTY%7C10YAT-APG------L!BZN%7C10YAT-APG------L&dateTime.timezone=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET+(UTC+1)+/+CEST+(UTC+2)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
price_hide = soup.find(class_='dv-value-cell')
print(price_hide)
```

To which I got so far:

```
<td class="dv-value-cell">
<span       onclick="showDetail('eu.entsoe.emfip.transmission_domain.r2.presentation.entity.DayAheadPricesMongoEntity', '5bb0b150623a7295d97e9b6d', '2018-09-30T22:00:00.000Z', 'PRICE', 'CET');">59.53</span>
```

But how do I scrape the whole table?

Comment: First do price_hides = soup.find_all(class_='dv-value-cell') to get all tds.
Then price_hide.text to get Price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find all the `td` tags and then in each of them extract the text value inside the `span` tag

```
timestamps=soup.find_all("td",class_="first")
prices=soup.find_all("td",class_="dv-value-cell")

for t,p in zip(timestamps,prices):
    print(t.text.strip()," ",p.span.text.strip())


00:00 - 01:00   59.53
01:00 - 02:00   56.10
02:00 - 03:00   51.41
03:00 - 04:00   47.38
04:00 - 05:00   47.59
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for the prices, but I wanted to get the whole table, including the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get('https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/dayAheadPrices/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=01.10.2018+00:00%7CCET%7CDAY&biddingZone.values=CTY%7C10YAT-APG------L!BZN%7C10YAT-APG------L&dateTime.timezone=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET+(UTC+1)+/+CEST+(UTC+2)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
price_hide = soup.find_all(class_='dv-value-cell')
for price in price_hide:
    print(price.text.rstrip().lstrip())
```

With the following output:

```
59.53
56.10
51.41
47.38
47.59
51.61
69.13
77.32
...
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm trying to get the whole table, timestamps included. Should I do the same for the other column and then merge them or is there any simpler, cleaner method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `soup.find_all()` instead of `soup.find()` and then apply further logic to extract the required results.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get('https://transparency.entsoe.eu/transmission-domain/r2/dayAheadPrices/show?name=&defaultValue=false&viewType=TABLE&areaType=BZN&atch=false&dateTime.dateTime=01.10.2018+00:00%7CCET%7CDAY&biddingZone.values=CTY%7C10YAT-APG------L!BZN%7C10YAT-APG------L&dateTime.timezone=CET_CEST&dateTime.timezone_input=CET+(UTC+1)+/+CEST+(UTC+2)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
price_hide = soup.find_all(['tr'])
for price in price_hide:
    print(''.join(price.get_text("|", strip=True).split()))
```

With the following output:

```
MTU|Day-aheadPrice
[EUR/MWh]
00:00-01:00|59.53
01:00-02:00|56.10
02:00-03:00|51.41
03:00-04:00|47.38
04:00-05:00|47.59
05:00-06:00|51.61
06:00-07:00|69.13
07:00-08:00|77.32
08:00-09:00|84.97
09:00-10:00|79.56
10:00-11:00|73.70
11:00-12:00|72.00
12:00-13:00|65.20
13:00-14:00|62.05
14:00-15:00|61.96
15:00-16:00|62.41
16:00-17:00|61.98
17:00-18:00|60.42
18:00-19:00|69.93
19:00-20:00|75.00
```